# Did John 14:6 apply before the birth of Christ?

Tags: sin, heaven, judaism

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Who saved people before ~33AD?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1824/who-saved-people-before-33ad)

`Jesus saith unto him, I am the way, the truth, and the life: no man cometh unto the Father, but by me. (John 14:6)`. Did this apply before the birth of Christ? I've heard that Jews, before and after Christ, believe that the sacrificial lamb was taken literally. Essentially, was there any way of entrance to heaven before Jesus?

Comment: [A prior question](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/12420/according-to-roman-catholic-teaching-did-people-who-died-in-old-testament-times) might be relevant here.

Answer (score 1):

Enoch (Genesis 5) and Elijah (in 2 Kings 2) were both taken away by God and did not die.  Whether they went to "heaven" or not, they did go to God.

Since Jesus is fully God, and is outside time with God, then even before he was born a man and died on the cross for our sins, he was the way, the truth, and the life.  Why should God be limited by time, part of his creation?